# Best approach to save user id in phone memory(or cache) once authenticated

Tags: flutter

What is the best approach to save user ID in phone's memory once authenticated so that user don't need to login again once the app is terminated.Should i use user Shared preferences plugin in dart??
Also, I am using firebase phone auth in my flutter app and all i want is user don't have to put phone number again and again.Once authenticated the user should bypass phone auth screen, if he/she opens app again.

Comment: You can use shared preference for this thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharedPreference plugin is a good plugin for a situation like this, but since you are working with firebase, You don't really need it. Once you log in with firebase, the current user remains available until you logout, so there is no need to save the details in sharedPreference.
 You can check for the user by doing this:

```
FirebaseAuth  _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
        if(currentUser != null){
           print(currentUser.uid);
        }else{
            //go to phone login page or something like that
        }
```

Use this to signout

```
_auth.signOut();
```